# Methods of comparing prices

Tags: algorithm

I will create a list of products that I wish to buy. Let's say they are all given a unique reference code. I have a list of suppliers I can buy from and for convenience each supplier uses the same reference code for each product.

Some suppliers charge shipping. Others only charge shipping if you spend less than a certain amount. Some suppliers discount certain products if you buy them more than once but there may be restrictions (such as by 1 get 1 free).

It is extremely easy to take the list of products I want to buy and tally up the total it would cost to buy all of them from each supplier. What I want to do though is create a script to work out whether it would be better to split the order.

For example:

Retailer A charges:
Product A - £5
Product B - £10
Product C - £10
Product D - £10
Shipping - £5

Retailer B charges:
Product A - £5
Product B - £12
Product C - £12
Product D - £30
Shipping - £5 - free if spending £20 or more

In this case, if I wanted to buy Product C only, the cheapest would be from retailer A.

If I wanted to buy:
1x Product A
2x Product B
1x Product D

The cheapest would be retailer B (because of the free delivery) for products A and B and to then split the order and purchase product D from retailer A (as the price even with delivery is significantly lower even with delivery included).

So in my head it's not a complex task and I can work it out very easily on paper. The question is, how I would translate this into code. I'm not looking for the code to do it - just some guidance on the theory of how to implement it.

Comment: Brute force: generate all possible combinations, determine the cost of each and pick the cheapest one.

Comment: I feel this problem is NP...am I wrong?

Comment: @Calpis You probably meant [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Np-complete), there's a difference.

Comment: (About) how many products do you wish to buy and (about) how many suppliers are there? This will give some insight as to whether you need to do something faster than brute force.

Comment: There are approximately 10 suppliers. The products being ordered will vary every few months but essentially it will be around 50 unique products... varying quantities of each. @Dukeling I hadn't heard of NP-complete before and rather liked the sentence on Wikipedia: "Although any given solution to such a problem can be verified quickly, there is no known efficient way to locate a solution in the first place; indeed, the most notable characteristic of NP-complete problems is that no fast solution to them is known.". I suspect that sums it up! Brute force.

Comment: More specifically, exactly algorithms are very, very, very slow. Brute force will take 50^10 (each product at each supplier), which modern computers may have a bit of a hard time with. There are of course [approximation algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm) as well, which run a lot quicker but don't give an optimal solution.

Comment: @ChrisEvans the NP-completeness issue is subtle and does not mean brute force is the best choice. NP-completeness refers to (1) worst case complexity and (2) asymptotic behavior. Regarding (1), this means that it is possible that in your specific instance, there may be algorithms or heuristics that do better than brute force. For (2), an algorithm may not be asymptotically better than brute force, but be much better in practice - for example, if an algorithm always achieves 1/4 of the time used by brute force, it will be practically better but not asymptotically better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we restrict the problem to simply choosing which vendor to buy each product from, and you get a vendor-dependent reduction in shipping cost if you spend a vendor-dependent amount, then you can formulate your problem as an integer linear program (IP or ILP), which is a good strategy for problems suspected to be NP-hard because there has been a lot of research and software packages developed that try to solve ILP fast in practice.  You can read about linear programming and ILP online. An ILP problem instance has variables, linear constraints on the variables, and a linear objective you want to minimize or maximize. Here's the ILP set up for your problem:

For each product that a vendor sells, you have one vendor-product variable that tells how many of the product you will purchase from the vendor.  For each of these variables you have a constraint that the variable must be >= 0.  For each product you wish to buy, you have a constraint that the sum of all the vendor-product variables for that product must equal the total number of the product that you wish to buy.

Then for each vendor that offers a shipping discount, you have a shipping discount variable which will be either 0 if you don't get the discount, or 1 if you do.  For each one of these shipping discount variables, you have constraints that the variable must be >=0 and <= 1;  you also have a constraint that says when you multiply each vendor-product variable for the vendor by the vendor's price for that product, and add it all up for the vendor (so you get the total amount you are spending at the vendor), this amount is >= the vendor's shipping discount variable multiplied by the vendor's minimum amount you need to spend to get the discount.

You also have for each vendor a vendor variable which is 1 if you use the vendor, and 0 if you don't. For each of these vendor variables A, you have constraints 1 >= A > =0 and also for each vendor-product variable B for the vendor, you have a constraint A >= B/N, where N is the total number of items you want to buy.

Finally the objective you want to maximize is made by multiplying each vendor-product variable by the vendor's price for that product, adding it all up (call this part of the objective X), and then multiplying each vendor's shipping discount variable by the shipping cost reduction you get if you get the discount, adding it all up (call this part of the objective Y), and multiplying each vendor variable by the vendor's undiscounted shipping cost, adding it all up (call this part of the objective Z) then your objective is simply to minimize X - Y + Z. This is all you need to define the ILP, then you can feed it into an ILP solver and hopefully get a solution quickly.

Comment: Also, if the ILP takes too long to solve, you can try linear programming relaxation to get an approximate solution (also you can read about online).

Answer (score 0):

Mixed Integer Linear Programming is ok for your problem.

You can use a free solver such as Coin Clp. If you want to know about commercial MILP solver performances, you can find some benchmarks there : http://plato.asu.edu/bench.html.

If you want to have a rough idea of the time required to solve your problem, you can run your problem on NEOS Server : http://www.neos-server.org/neos/.

When you have a lot of 0-1 variable, you can also contemplate to use Constraint Programming which often suits better for heavy combinatorial problems.

Both MILP and CP algorithms use branch and bound technique, which is faster than naive enumeration.

Cheers