# Comparing multiple price options for many customers algorithmically

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, statistics, branch-and-bound

We have 1,000,000 customers. The cost of goods sold for each of them can be expressed as price A or price B.

Price A << Price B.

Price A and Price B are not linear to each other. In some cases B is 2 times as expensive, in some it is 100 times.

cost of all the customers on A is

min( (sum(A)/count(A)) , 100 ) * count(A)
Effectively, the average cost of all the customers on A will be rounded up to 100 if it is less than 100.

There is no such restriction on B.

I would like to spend the least amount of money on their goods.

How do I maximize

cost=min( (sum(A)/count(A)) , 100 ) * count(A) + sum(B)
I keep seeing this as a form of a dual knapsack problem, but I can't get it right ...

I'd be probably solving this in Python, most likely, although I doubt that matters much.

I've done manual analyses by assigning scores to x y z and filtering based upon that, I'm interested in more of a computational solution.

Any approaches to recommend?

Comment: Possible resource : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598397/methods-of-comparing-prices

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly. Can you give a small example to explain it clearly?

Comment: You have a choice of 2 prices for 200k different items. But it's not clear from your question what your model is for your profit, given a particular set of choices for prices. That makes it impossible to answer your question.

Comment: "I still have to pay $100", I assume you meant "I still have to pay atleast $100" because your individual bill maybe greater than $100 in which case I assume you will have to pay the actual bill amount. Also, do you have the data of actual usages for each customer for each of TV, data and voice?

Comment: I tried again here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455985/searching-for-the-best-fit-price-for-multiple-customers

Answer (score 0):

Restated in a much easier way elsewhere.

[Searching for the best fit price for multiple customers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455985/searching-for-the-best-fit-price-for-multiple-customers)

Comment: .. this is not actually an answer to the question.

Comment: @RizwanKassim just click 'close' under the text of the question. It doesn't 'delete' it, but closes it so it won't show up for others anymore.